# jquery - variable inside a contains selector

Tags: jquery

I am still learing jquery. I got a problem when passing the value of a textbox inside a selector.

I have this code

```
jQuery('input#id_search').live('input', function() {
 varSearch = jQuery(this).val();
 jQuery("a:contains('String')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
});
```

the code above works fine if I hard coded the value in `a:contains` which is a `String`. 
But when I change the `String` to a variable it does not work at all..

here is my code.

```
jQuery("a:contains(**varSearch**)").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: jQuery("a:contains(" + varSearch + ")").css("text-decoration", "underline");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('input', '#id_search', function() {
        var search = this.value;
        $('a').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().indexOf(search) != -1;
        }).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    });
});
```

Note that older browsers don't have support for the `input` event, and that `live()` is deprecated, and you should replace `document` above with the closest non-dynamic parent.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a variable, it needs to be outside your quotations:

```
jQuery("a:contains(" + varSearch + ")").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```